# Who was Hajime talking to at the end of Gatchaman Crowds?

Tags: gatchaman-crowds

At the end of the last episode:

> She called her mother to tell her that no matter what happens, "I'm just me". Then after the credits, Hajime was tapping her chest and was having a conversation with someone with another voice. Who was she talking to? Was that supposed to be Katze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's Katze.

Most of the time, Katze talks with a high pitch, especially when bullying people. However, when Katze is not in control of the situation, his/her voice drops. This can be heard several times in the battle between O.D. and Katze that starts at 6:05 in the same episode. It's the same voice.

Besides, at the end of the series everybody else likes Hajime; who except Katze would claim to be sickened by her? :-)

Comment: So I guess that leads one to ask, where is Katze and why is he with (sounds almost involuntarily) with Hajime? Is he trapped inside her?

Comment: I've been wondering too! Maybe he's been reduced to the size of a NOTE....?

Answer (score 1):

She isn't actually tapping her chest. She is gesturing/playing with the new red ribbon she is wearing. Given how she is talking to Katze, and he seems to be with her, and she has just gotten the red ribbon, and how Katze's signature color is red/pink, I think the logical conclusion is that he has been sealed inside the ribbon.

That said, a lot of loose ends are still around, and many people have speculated that an extended ending will be on the blu-ray detailing what happened at the end of the series

Answer (score 0):

Everything surrounding the ending was clarified in an extended cut of the final episode called [Gatchaman Crowds: Embrace](http://myanimelist.net/anime/23703/Gatchaman_Crowds:_Embrace).