# What happened to Berg Katze?

Tags: gatchaman-crowds

Before Berg Katze went to fight OD Hajime asks him if later they can meet up somewhere. after everything has clamed down Berg Katze is trying to stir up trouble by shape shifting and attempting to get people to turn on each other using the Crowds however after that fails be leaves disappointed.

After that Hajime is seen waiting for him where they agreed to meet before calling her mother, during which the scene is focused on her chest.

After the credits when Hajime goes to leave there are shots focusing on her chest with sometimes tapping/pointing to herself. as she walks out she is announcing her plans before we hear Berg Katze reply acting all negative about it by saying it'll suck.

[This answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/5360/1587) confirms that is it Berg Katze that Hajime is talking to but I am wondering, what happened to him which cased him to now be with Hajime like this?

Comment: related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/who-was-hajime-talking-to-at-the-end-of-gatchaman-crowds

Comment: @LoganM all that question does is confirm that it is Katze but it seems though i asked what [Jon Lin is asking](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/who-was-hajime-talking-to-at-the-end-of-gatchaman-crowds#comment5038_5360) (to be honest i didn't know of the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Berg Katze's note (and himself) was absorbed into Hajime. He is currently trapped and powerless inside her "chest". Your confusion stems from the fact that the scene never made it to the TV series.

---

Episode 12 has two versions. There is a "director's cut" version that was shipped as an OVA, showing the confrontation between Hajime and Katze, when she gains control of Katze's golden note (I did not watch it).

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Gatchaman_Crowds_episodes):

> `OVA          "Embrace"           January 22, 2014`
>   Director's cut of episode 12. Scenes about the civilians and the Crowds are expanded on, while the battle between Katze and OD is cut. An added segment shows Hajime's face-off with Katze, with her fusing herself with them by absorbing their NOTE into her body.

Alas, Katze is not that powerless, since it seems he can take over Hajime's Gatchaman form:

Again [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatchaman_Crowds#Characters):

> Her original NOTE and Gatchaman form takes on red accents after fusing with Katze, and her Gatchaman form's face switches from blue eyes to a red smile when Katze is in command.

IMO, it was a bad choice to leave Hajime's showdown to the OVA (even if it was financially good for them), since it is important to the Crowds-Insight plot.